# Where and how to check that hibernate cache really works

Tags: hibernate, caching

I am new in the hibernate's cache area.

1. What is the easiest way to check that the cache really works?
2. Does hibernate gnerate the same sql statements when cache is on?
3. Should it be any folder/file in filesystem with stored data (second-level cache)?
4. How to check how much cache is currently used?

Regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. You can enable [Hibernate statistics generation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-statistics) be setting `hibernate.generate_statistics` property to `true`. Then you can monitor cache hit/miss count via `SessionFactory.getStatistics()`.

   Also, when SQL logging is enabled you can analyze cache behaviour by presence or absense of particular SQL queries.
2. It depends on many factors. See [21.2. The Second Level Cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-cache) and [21.4. The Query Cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-querycache)
3. It depends on cache provider and its configuration. For example, [EhCache](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate) can be configured to overflow to disk.
4. `SessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics()` provides this information.

Comment: +1. The cache provider also often provides JMX beans that can be asked for their own statistics

Answer (score 7):

I have found [nice tool](http://hibernate-jcons.sourceforge.net/) that vizuliaze hibernate usage (also cache).
Additionaly in these [articles (here is part one)](http://blog.dynatrace.com/2009/02/16/understanding-caching-in-hibernate-part-one-the-session-cache/) there is quite good explanation how the hibernate cache works (see also related links). 
There is also nice example with analysis steps.

Anyway thanks for answers.